# Objective-C iOS How do I add UIPageControl to my CollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a collectionView with pagedEnable and horizontal scroll.
I just want to add dot of pageControl to my collectionView when scrolling.

Comment: Add a PageControl over the CollectionView and implement ScrollViewDidScroll of UIScrollViewDelegate and set current page of PageControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the scroll view's delegate method as follows:-

Say `collectionViewTestimonial` : Name(IBOutlet) of your collection view, `pageControlTestimonial`: Name of page control

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = collectionViewTestimonial.frame.size.width;
    pageControlTestimonial.currentPage = collectionViewTestimonial.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
}
```

Comment: It work fine. Thank! :)

Answer (score 2):

Set number of pages in the pageControl

```
NSUInteger numberOfCells = 10;
_pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfCells;
```

Implement scrollView delegate method

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 // Suppose your collectionview cell width is equal to your screen size
 CGFloat collectionViewCellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;     
_pageControl.currentPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionViewCellWidth);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 // Suppose your collectionview cell width is equal to your screen size
 CGFloat collectionViewCellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;     
_pageControl.currentPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionViewCellWidth);
}
```

Comment: I think you answer the wrong question.